# Cannot invoke load data with list type NSURL...loading local web view content

Tags: swift, uiwebview, swift2, nsurl

I am attempting to make a login page with a mp4 playing in the background through a webview object. This is my code and the error is in this line.

```
webView.loadData(url!, MIMEType: "video/mp4", textEncodingName: String(), baseURL: NSURL())
```

The error is

```
"cannot invoke 'loadData' with argument list of type'(NSURL....'"
```

I don't know what to try next. Thank you in advance.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController!

func loginVideo(){

    webView.frame = self.view.frame

    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie", ofType:"mp4")
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath!)

    webView.loadData(url!, MIMEType: "video/mp4", textEncodingName: String(), baseURL: NSURL())
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = false;

    let filter = UIView()
    filter.frame = self.view.frame
    filter.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    filter.alpha = 0.05
    self.view.addSubview(filter)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use NSData in the place of the URL. The actual signature of the loadData method is,

```
wkWebView.loadData(data: NSData, MIMEType: String, characterEncodingName: String, baseURL: NSURL)
```

try replacing the below lines,

```
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath!)
webView.loadData(url!, MIMEType: "video/mp4", textEncodingName: String(), baseURL: NSURL())
```

with

```
let data = NSData(filePath!)
webView.loadData(data, MIMEType: "video/mp4", textEncodingName: String(), baseURL: NSURL())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me the error  "Cannot find initializer for NSData that accepts an argument of type String()"

Comment: I used `let data = (NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie", ofType:"mp4"))!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    
        
        webView.loadData(data, MIMEType: "video/mp4", textEncodingName: String(), baseURL: NSURL()) ` The only issue is that the Sinulator is not playing the video.